# Proving continuity exists here

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that continuity at $0$ exists where

$$f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{(x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2)}$$
and $$f(0,0)=0$$

Given $\epsilon > 0$ we need to find a $\delta>0$ such that

$$|x-y|< \delta => |\frac{xy}{(x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2)}|< \epsilon$$

Since as we close on $0$ $x^2+y^2 ≤ 2$

$x+y ≤2$ and $xy≤1$

Can we then choose $\delta$ such that $$\delta = \frac{1}{4\epsilon}$$

since $\epsilon >0$ we can find $\delta$ for each epsilon. I believe there shouldn'T be a problem, but see as $\epsilon$ gets decreased $\delta$ keeps getting bigger, would that present a problem?

Comment: Hint: $y=x^2$. ${}{}{}$

Comment: It sure doesn't look continuous at (0,0) to me.  Convert to polar and you get $\frac {\tan2\theta}{2r^2}$ and for any $r$ there is a $\theta$ such that $f(r,\theta)>\epsilon$

Comment: No conversion to polar coordinates please

Comment: Can someone explain what is wrong with my $\delta$

Comment: What about $x^2-y^2?$

Comment: I need an explanation of why the $\delta = \frac{1}{4 \epsilon}$ doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(\sqrt{2}x,x)=$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3x^2}=+\infty$$

$\implies f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.